# Google Optimize stopped adding utm_expid to URL as params?

Tags: javascript, google-optimize

Until now I collected Google optimize Experiment ID for a/b page testing from the URL params (utm_expid).
But for some reason, they stopped providing it, Is there a way to continue collecting the Experiment ID and if there is, what is the best way to do it?

Before:
https://wwww.Domain.com/?utm_expid=.SdQHL1lMSi-Au9qe-MKg3Q.0&utm_referrer=

Now:
https://wwww.Domain.com/

Answer (score 1):

Google optimize stopped adding utm_expid to the URL probably for aesthetic reasons.

Instead, you can get it through cookies, the cookie is named _gaexp.

```
function getCookieByName(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');

  for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1);
    if (c.indexOf(name) != -1) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
  }

  return "";
}

getCookieByName("_gaexp")
```